# Should the [concurency] tag be burninated?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

Stack Overflow tag [concurency](/questions/tagged/concurency) should probably being burninated, instead to be used as a [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/concurrency/synonyms) for [concurrency](/questions/tagged/concurrency).

Comment: What is the problem? In this way we at least won't risk a common misspelling from reoccurring.

Comment: @Bart it is a typo. *Concurency* is not an English word AFAIK.

Comment: I know. And it won't actually appear like that on questions, being replaced with its correct version instead.

Comment: Ah, so it is good practice? I didn't know it was good to use common misspelled word as synonyms to avoid the issue.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Only for something that is consistently a problem.

Comment: Don't know if that is good/recommended practice, but I don't see it doing any harm in this case. Am I missing something?

Comment: @animuson Ok, thanks for the info. So is this the case for "concurency"? Should I delete my question? Or is it better if you post an answer and I accept it?

Comment: [status-completed] @anim?

Comment: I made it an answer @LorenzoDonati. Perhaps something like this will pop up again, and then we'll have a dupe for it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The very fact that [concurency](/questions/tagged/concurency) is a synonym of the correct [concurrency](/questions/tagged/concurrency) means it can do no harm. Anyone who would use the rather common misspelling of that word, will have the correct tag added to the question anyway. For something that is (most likely, though I have no data on this) as frequently misspelled as "concurrency", it seems like a nice bonus.

That does however not imply that anyone should go around and create pseudo-commonly misspelled tags just to make them synonyms. Or even that a simple misspelling should immediately be made a synonym of the existing correct tag. It's just handy in cases that would pop up time and time again.

Comment: Your second paragraph reminds me of domain squatting.